# Problems with about box in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, expression-blend, about-box

I have tried adding an about box in blend using the method described here:

[About Window or About Box in WPF 3.5 (VS2008)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411952/about-window-or-about-box-in-wpf-3-5-vs2008)

However, I end up getting an error saying that the namespace System.Windows.Forms doesn't exist.

Does blend not support this namespace?  if so, is there another method for adding an about box?

Comment: Regarding the answer to the other question, I can't imagine why you would want to use Winforms to do an about box in WPF. This is going to result in inconsistent look and feel, a confusing code base, and excessive assemblies being loaded. Frankly, it's cringe-worthy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a normal WPF Window and make it look like an about box (add text blocks for product name, version, copyright ...)

There is nothing special about the WinForms about box, it's just a normal form preloaded with common about box controls, there is no reason to use it from WPF.

Comment: This makes sense.  I'm not really sure why I didn't do this in the first place.  Thank you for the help.